# How do I resize an ext4 partition programmatically?

Tags: c, ext4

I want to resize an ext4 partition programmatically in C. I believe I can use [libparted](http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/api/) to resize the partition, but not the file system? Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: You could have a look at the source of resize2fs.

Comment: which can be found [here](http://git.kernel.org/?p=fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git;a=summary).

Answer (score 0):

Use `resize_fs()`.

Take a look here for example of usage:

http://fossies.org/dox/e2fsprogs-1.42.4/resize2fs_8c_source.html#l00072

Comment: Thanks! It should be noted `main` of `main.c` does a lot of work prior to calling that function.